# Get and set JScrollBar position in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I've a `JTable` that is a view for a large amount of data retrieved from a database.

For this reason, I thought to show only a part of these data (e.g. first 100 rows) and, when user reach the end of the JTable with the `JScrollBar`, the `JTable` will show other rows.

So I'm looking for a mechanism that lets me know when a scrollbar is at the end of the JTable and only at that moment, perform another query. And, when I get the new `List`, set the scrollbar position to the one before the new query, just for a "continuity" to the user.

Could anyone give some tips to achieve this task?

Thank you in adance

Comment: The scroll bar has a model -- I would recommend studying it, learning about listeners that can be attached to it... I'll bet if you do this that you could figure this one out on your own.

Comment: *"I've a JTable that is a view for a large amount of data retrieved from a database."* How many records are we talking about, here?  I've made tables from the Unicode code points (about 1.1 million) that were fine.

Comment: I don't know how many items we're talking about because these records are stored in a database for 30 days. I know only that a such query makes my application slow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may saw before, most of the JComponents has `model`s and they are being rendered according to their model. So if you can access the `model`, you can access the events and the data you need for your purpose.

According to this, `JScrollBar` also follows this rule and has it's own model. By getting this model (which is a `BoundedRangeModel`) and adding a `ChangeListener` you may create what you want for retrieving next page of data from database.

Important point is to find the rule which is ruling over the `JScrollBar` model. `BoundedRangeModel` has some properties to which you can refer. Some of them which are important to you in this case are:

- `valueIsAdjusting`
- `value`
- `extent`
- `maximum`

`ValueIsAdjusting` is the one that indicates are we in the middle of the process of changing the range of `BoundedRangeModel` or not. To be frank, it means: Is the `scrollBar` getting dragged?

Other properties `value`, `extent` and `maximum` are the ones you can use to find out whether the `ScrollBar` reached the end of the range or not. If the `Scrollbar` reached there, it is the time for retrieving next page of data from database. To indicate this situation the following equation must apply:

`value` + `extent` = `maximum`

Following snippet code may clarify the above explanations:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BoundedRangeModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class LiveJTableDemoFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 200;
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    //
    private JTable table;
    private String[] columnNames;
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;

    public LiveJTableDemoFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        //
        columnNames = new String[]{"ID", "A", "B", "C", "D"};
        //
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0); 
        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        //
        final JScrollPane p = new JScrollPane();
        p.setViewportView(table);
        p.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                BoundedRangeModel scModel = p.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel();
                boolean valueIsAdjusting = scModel.getValueIsAdjusting();
                if(!valueIsAdjusting){
                    if(scModel.getValue() + scModel.getExtent() == scModel.getMaximum()){
                        retrieveData();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //
        retrieveData();
        //
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    //Dummy method to simulate retrieving data from database
    private void retrieveData(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            Object[] rowData = new Object[columnNames.length];
            //
            rowData[0] = tableModel.getDataVector().size();
            rowData[1] = "A";
            rowData[2] = "B";
            rowData[3] = "C";
            rowData[4] = "D";
            //
            tableModel.addRow(rowData); 
        }
        //tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LiveJTableDemoFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

Another way to do this is to add an `AdjustmentListener` to the vertical `JScrollBar` and use the event to get the `value` and `ValueIsAdjusting`. Also you have to get the `extent` and `maximum` from the `JScrollBar`'s `model`. Following snippet shows the alternative way:

```
    final JScrollPane p = new JScrollPane();
    p.setViewportView(table);
    p.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener(){ 
        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            // here the control if vertical scroll bar has reached the maximum value
            if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                JScrollBar source = (JScrollBar) e.getAdjustable();
                int extent = source.getModel().getExtent();
                int maximum = source.getModel().getMaximum();
                if(e.getValue() + extent == maximum){
                    retrieveData();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @STaefi . I wanna make you another question. Before reading your answer, I had followed this approach: myScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener(){ // here the control if vertical scroll bar has reached the maximum value}. Is that a correct way or your solution is better than this? Thank you so much again

Comment: @user2896152: Sorry for the late answer for I was sick. I can tell that it is not incorrect to use `AdjustmentListener` associated with the vertical `JScrollBar`, but the input event has only two of the related properties which are: `ValueIsAdjusting` and `Value` and it doesn't have the values of `extent` and the `maximum`. So in either ways you have to get the reference of the JScrollBar's `model`. Check my updated answer.